# EntityFramework for Python

Tags: python, entity-framework

What is that standard replacement of .Net's EntityFramework for Python?

**Note:** I mean CPython, not IronPython.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is called "ORM". SQLAlchemy is often used as a general purpose ORM for Python but there is a lot of other solutions, see for example [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HigherLevelDatabaseProgramming).

Comment: Oh, thank you. Didn't realize what it was called.